# java subclass state not changing when function called

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I've got a super class called Game that has a function `pickPlayers()` and an `ArrayList<Player> players` that contains the ones that are chosen, and a subclass `ConsoleGame` that extends it. The problem is when I make an instance of `ConsoleGame` and call `myInstance.pickPlayers()`, the instance's arraylist players is empty. Any ideas? I figure this is mostly a conceptual question, but if it helps, here's some of the code:

Here's the class Game:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Game {
    protected String name;
    protected int numPlayers;
    protected ArrayList<Player> players;

    public Game(String n, int np) {
        name = n;
        numPlayers = np;
    }

    protected void pickPlayers(ArrayList<Player> players) {
        /**
         * Choose players at random from the array passed in to play the game
         * Parameters:
         *     ArrayList<Player> players - the array of players
         * Returns:
         *     void
         */
        // choose players at random from players to play the game
        for(int j = 0; j < numPlayers; j++) {
            players.add(players.get(GameNight.generator.nextInt(players.size() - 1)));
        }
    }

    protected abstract void play();
}
```

and here's the subclass BoardGame:

```
public class BoardGame extends Game {

    /**
     * Luck factor of the game
     */
    private double luckFactor;

    /**
     * Constructor, takes three args to set the instance variables
     * @param n Name of the game
     * @param np Number of players that can play the game at once
     * @param l Luck factor
     */
    public BoardGame(String n, int np, double l) {
        super(n,np);
        luckFactor = l;
    }

    /**
     * Plays the game and chooses a winner.  Winner is chosen to be
     * the person with the largest value of 
     * intelligence + (luck * luckFactor), where luck refer's to the
     * Player's luckiness and luckFactor refers to the Game's instance
     * variable.  This method returns nothing but does call youWin()
     * on the Player that won the game.
     */
    public void play() {
       // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post `Game` class?

Comment: we need more code, especially constructor of class Game and sequence of creating instance and calling methods in it until pickPlayers

Comment: posted the entire class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void pickPlayers(ArrayList<Player> players) {        
   players.get(..) 
}
```

It's referencing to the local variable,you are [*shadowing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) your instance variable. In order to use instance property you have to refer with `this` 
then it would be.

```
this.players.get(..)
```

**NOTE**

By the way when you create a Game type `players` is null. May be you should init as an empty list.

Comment: +1 - In fact, now that we see his code, this is exactly what he is doing!

Comment: Haha initializing the empty list ended up doing it. Thanks :D!

Comment: @StephenC OP give me a great hint `..the instance's arraylist players is empty..` now he post code so edit code, thanks for upvoting